Objection to indirect proof in Intuitionism
From my understanding, Brouwer's conception of intuitionism is that mathematical objects only exist in the mind once they have been constructed. And we can create constructions using computable operations like multiplication. I know intuitionistically that there exists some number that equals 10234 x 289959 even if I don't perform the calculation explicitly in my head.
Regarding classical number theory, I know every natural number exists and can be constructed. That is, if I ask an oracle to give me any natural number, I can construct it just by counting up to it. Intuitionistically, it doesn't really make sense to say "every natural number is constructible", even though I can count arbitrarily high. I will never "complete" my counting of the natural numbers; infinity is never actualized in intuitionistic mathematics.
My question is about indirect existence proofs. That is, from
P : "not for all x, not A(x)",

I can deduce
Q : "there exists an x, such that A(x)".

Classically, this is correct and the proof of which follows from LEM (which is not accepted intuitionistically). My question is, why is this not acceptable intuitionistically in the following different approach. Constructive existence proofs of Q often describe a computable algorithm that will terminate in finite time with the promise of producing an object x that satisfies A(x). Suppose I know P intuitionistically. My algorithm is simple, count from 0 using the successor and check A(x) for each x. This will terminate. Why? If it is not the case, then for each x that does not satisfy A, its successor x' will also fail to satisfy A. Then by induction I can prove
R : "for all x, not A(x)".

But I know this cannot be the case because I have P. So I can promise that the algorithm will terminate.
I suspect that there are some issues here and that I am certainly not the first to think of this. My guess is that in proving that my algorithm will terminate, I had to first prove it will not and then get a contradiction. But intuinistically, this only proves that my algorithm will not not terminate.
But I know that it must terminate! (if not only classically). That is an actual claim about the real world in finite time (only if it does terminate which leads to the halting problem). So if I understand this correctly, Brouwer challenges me to find an x satisfying A. And I claim that I can count up to such and x. Brouwer responds "I don't believe you" and I'm done. I could if I wanted to simply count up in front of him for a lifetime until I actually do find such an x. But then Brouwer says "that little story you told of you counting for me doesn't prove anything". And only will believe me if I actually do count. If it were feasible to count up to such an x in the scope of a paper or in a year or a lifetime that would be a valid proof.
Is there anything more to that objection? What is the correct intuitionistic/construct interpretation of this algorithm. That is, why or why not does it hold any water? It seems so absurd to not accept that that will not terminate. I have gathered from intuitionistic/constructive logic is that it is extremely strict and limiting in what it holds to be true.
Edit: Assume that A is computable, so that determining whether or not A(x) is true takes finite time.

Congratulations, you've discovered Markov's principle. It is not intuitionistically valid, but holds in the effective topos.

This is too technical for the philosophy site.  Try to shorten the question a bit and I would suggest posting it either at MSE or MO.

See the link provided by @NaïmFavier above: "If a Turing machine does not run forever, then it halts." The claim that a T-machine does not run forever is ¬∀n¬H(n) but from an Intuitionistc point of view we cannot derive from it ∃nH(n).

@BENG "This will terminate. Why? If it is not the case, then for each x that does not satisfy A, its successor x' will also fail to satisfy A. Then by induction I can prove R : "for all x, not A(x)"." No you cannot.

To make matters even more complicated, there are different versions of constructivism: Russian, Bishop and Heyting. In Russian constructivism, the Markov principle holds, so your argument would be OK. In Heyting's intuitionistic logic it is not a theorem. More precisely, the Markov rule is admissible but not derivable.

@Speakpigeon why is that the case? If I have "not A(x)" implies "not A(x')" for every x, can I not use induction to prove "for all x, not A(x)"? Or do things work different constructively?

Induction works just fine constructively, but your argument is not very clear. You're mixing object-level and meta-level.

@BENG "If I have "not A(x)" implies "not A(x')" for every x, can I not use induction to prove "for all x, not A(x)"?" I don't see how that could relate to my comment. - 2. ""not A(x)" implies "not A(x')"" That's obviously true. - 3. "If I have "not A(x)" implies "not A(x')" for every x," Now, that, what does it mean?

Intuitionists consider proof as a more strict game even than formalists and truth is an external semantic anyway and the only truth within the logical calculus is following all (derivable) rules. The explanation here is nothing but even in everyday life there's a subtle interpretable difference between 'like' and 'not unlike' which cannot be always reduced to 'like' in all use cases...

Even given ¬∀x.¬A(x), even classically, your algorithm may never halt, because it may be that the only xs that satisfy A(x) are nonstandard natural numbers. That happens if, for instance, (PA is consistent and) A(x) expresses that x encodes a proof in PA of Con(PA), and you work in the system PA + ¬∀x.¬A(x).
If, for a particular A, the machine does halt, then there is a constructive proof that it halts and a constructive proof of ∃x.A(x). Your argument might have weight if it was easier to prove the former than the latter, but it probably never is easier (I don't know how to formalize that, though).

Doesn't ¬∀x.¬A(x) imply Con(PA)? Since Con(PA) is a negative proposition, you can apply DNE to get ∃x.A(x), hence Con(PA)?

@NaïmFavier I added a mention that I'm assuming PA is consistent.

The answer by benrg is extremely misleading. Suppose you wish to stick to intuitionistic reasoning. This does not imply that you want the intended model of your reasoning to include non-standard natural numbers! Instead, you want your reasoning to apply to standard natural numbers (i.e. the ones you actually can reach by counting up from 0). So you would not assume any axioms or rules that you do not believe apply to standard natural numbers. Hence your reasoning can be used to justify ¬∀k∈ℕ ( ¬Q(k) ) ⇒ ∃k∈ℕ ( Q(k) ). The problem is not with non-standard natural numbers, but rather with the assumption that LEM holds for program halting! This is exactly equivalent to LEM for Σ1-sentences (in the arithmetical complexity hierarchy). Even though your reasoning (for computable A) only requires Σ1-LEM and not full LEM, if you think about it you would realize that it is impossible to justify Σ1-LEM without also being able to justify full LEM, because Σ[n+1]-LEM is simply equivalent to the assertion that the halting problem is well-defined for programs using the n-th halting oracle (where the 0th halting oracle is a computable function). Exactly why you believe that whether a given program on a given input halts or not also explains why you must believe that whether a given program that uses the 1st halting oracle on a given input halts or not.
So remember! Believing that the halting problem is well-defined implies belief in Σ1-LEM! And you can't justify it without also being able to justify full LEM! This is the real problem with intuitionism, at least for arithmetical sentences: You are essentially forced to not accept that the halting problem is well-defined.

This sounds false. The halting problem for M is the statement "Halts(M) ∨ ¬Halts(M)". Σ₁-LEM in your internal logic gives you a solution to the halting problem (which is why it is constructively bogus), but the problem is well-defined constructively. As previously, it seems you like to accuse others of being misleading while providing no less misleading answers yourself.

@NaïmFavier: You can't prove that LEM instance without Σ1-LEM. The asker is indeed using that LEM instance, which is what "halting problem is well-defined means". If you reject that LEM instance, then you do not have the halting problem in the usual sense, and in the sense used by the asker. As previously, you like to downvote others without having actual competence in logic.

Also, the fact that you cannot even understand what is wrong with benrg's post is yet more evidence of your incompetence. In your comment on that post you even said "Doesn't ¬∀x.¬A(x) imply Con(PA)? Since Con(PA) is a negative proposition, you can apply DNE to get ∃x.A(x), hence Con(PA)?", which is totally bogus since Con(PA) is a Π1-sentence.

The argument is indeed implicitly relying on some form of LEM in the metatheory, but this has nothing to do with the halting problem being well-defined.

You can say whatever you want, but your errors are obvious to any professional logician. Perhaps stop stalking me if you aren't actually interested in learning facts.

I am not stalking you; I was here before you. Instead of appealing to authority, you could maybe explain why you take "well-defined" to mean "solved in the metatheory".

@NaïmFavier: It does not mean "solved in the metatheory", and I clearly didn't say anything like that. The halting problem is not solvable in general in any metasystem. Instead of downvoting according to whim, you could maybe ask for clarification before downvoting. Why should I even spend time teaching you if you already assumed that I am wrong? If you don't want to remove your uninformed downvote, then I invite you to think for yourself; what does a "well-defined problem" mean precisely?

A "well-defined" problem is a proposition P (like Halts(M)). A solution is a (constructive) proof of P ∨ ¬P, or ∀M. P(M) ∨ ¬P(M).

@‍NaïmFavier: Then too bad for you, that's not at all what logicians think, and you would do well not to impose your definitions on others. In computation theory, a (decision) problem is a technical term that means not merely a proposition but a mapping from instances to answers. Such a mapping cannot be faithfully represented by a proposition schema in IFOL unless you have proven LEM for that schema. Neither can it be represented by a set in any intuitionistic set theory unless you have proven LEM for membership in that set. And a solution is not the problem.

And don't think that I have forgotten your other errors, including not understanding why benrg's belief about non-standard natural numbers is bogus, and not knowing that the "¬∀x.¬A(x)" in benrg's post would mean "¬Con(PA)" rather than "Con(PA)" (which you thought).

No, count the negations. If ∃x.A(x) is Con(PA) then ¬∀x.¬A(x) is ¬¬∃x.A(x) hence ¬¬Con(PA).

What is wrong with you? Do you even know the logical structure of Con(PA)? It is a Π1-sentence, as I stated in my second comment to you. Please reflect on yourself.

Yes, so what? Read carefully: "A(x) expresses that x encodes a proof in PA of Con(PA)". To be more exact ∃x.A(x) means Provable(Con(PA)). But anyway, this has nothing to do with your answer so I don't know why we're talking about it.

Anyway, you seem confused about the difference between a problem and its solution. The mapping of instances to answers is the solution. A problem is just a question, like "does this TM halt?". You don't need any kind of LEM to ask that question, as it is phrased in elementary (primitive recursive) terms.

You are the confused one. You clearly do not know how the term "problem" is used by experts, and are trying to impose your philosophically misguided views and definitions upon others. And it's clear to any logician that any sound theory that extends PA proves only true sentences about ℕ and so there cannot be any valid argument against the schema ( ¬∀k∈ℕ ( ¬Q(k) ) ⇒ ∃k∈ℕ ( Q(k) ) ). I give up on you.

Now that's just nonsense. There are topological models that refute Markov's principle, see the linked nLab article. Maybe if you didn't open your answer by attacking others I'd cut you some slack instead of assuming you know what you're talking about.

Just because there are semantic models for IFOL refuting Markov's principle means nothing for the real world naturals, which is what the asker was talking about. Don't be fooled into thinking there can be non-standard naturals in the real world. It's so silly that it's hard to believe anyone could be duped by people saying so, but look here we are.

I am discussing mathematical facts, not beliefs. I have no idea what you mean by the "real world naturals".

And in my answer I was discussing the asker's question, not posting for people who lack the desire to learn. Looks like you didn't even read the asker's question, which included "That is an actual claim about the real world in finite time".
